# Adjacency matrix generator

Tags: java, arrays, adjacency-matrix

My goal is to create an adjacency matrix generator (the only value elements can have is 0 or 1; it has to be symmetric, meaning element in [i][j] == element [j][i]) in Java.

I have some code, but the result is an nx5 matrix (if I establish n = 13, the resulting matrix is a 13x5 matrix). It is symmetric and the values of elements is bounded between 0-1, so that is not an issue. Another problem is I don't really know how to have an array without doubles, which is more of an aesthetical problem + ideally, the diagonal would be filled with "-" instead of zeroes, as it is now.

```
    Random random = new Random();
    double[][] array = new double[n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            int x = random.nextInt(2);
            array[i][j] = x;

            if (i != j)
            {
                array[j][i] = x;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {

            if (i == j || (i + j + 1) == n)
            {
                array[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for (double[] a : array)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what _resulting matrix is a 13x5_ means, but change `double[][] array` to `int[][] array`, and change the last for loop to display however needed.

Comment: The matrix that comes out of the code is not a square matrix as an adjacency matrix should be, instead the dimension of the matrix is 13x5 (not 13x13).

Comment: Still don't understand - `array` is defined as [n][n]...

Comment: Oh, it's alright, I finally resolved the dimension issue. Thank you for the other advice though!